# How to match {1,0} with a regular expression

Tags: regex

`?` or `{0,1}`

will **match** some pattern when necessary, but now I want to do it reversely.

Say, **don't match** if necessary.

What is the solution?

Comment: I've answered the question as below but it seems like everyone has misunderstood what you want. Perhaps you could give an example of how you would like it to match.

Comment: @Mask: You really need to re-state the question. It is very ambiguous and hard to answer. Try to add a sample of what you want to do.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just put a question mark after the `{0,1}`, as in `{0,1}?`, and it will prefer matching zero than one time. The question mark makes it "non-greedy", which means it will not swallow as much as possible.

Test (in Perl):

```
#! perl
use warnings;
use strict;

my $string = "abcdefghijk";

if ($string =~ /(..{0,1}?)/) {
    print "$1\n";
}
```

Prints

```
a
```

You can also use `??` in place of `{0,1}?`.

Comment: But what I want is to make it greedy,match if possible.

Comment: I want it to prefer matching one than zero time.

Comment: That's what `?` and `{0,1}` do *by default*. Regex is greedy unless noted otherwise. `?` and `{0,1}` do match if *possible*, not if *necessary* (as you stated).

Answer (score 1):

> `?` or `{0,1}` will match some pattern when necessary, but now I want to do it reversely.

No, `?` or `{0,1}` will match some pattern if *possible*. Regex is greedy by default.

To make them match when *necessary*, they need to look like `??` or `{0,1}?`.

It seems you already have what you want.

> Say, **don't match** if necessary.

Saying "don't match" is generally something between difficult and impossible in regex. Unless you come up with a real sample of what you need to do, this is hard to answer.

Answer (score 0):

So, you need "two or more"? Then try this: `{2,}`

Answer (score 0):

It sounds to me like you're looking for a negative assertion.  The syntax for that is usually `(?!...)`

For example, `A(?!B)C` will match A then C, but not if the beginning of C matches B.