# Regular expression to match 0 or 1

Tags: javascript, regex

I need a regexp to match either 0 or 1 entered into a field and no other characters at all, neither numeric nor alphas. How can I do it?

Comment: What's wrong with `if (x===0||x===1)`?

Comment: I agree with @elclanrs, this doesn't really sound like something you would need a regex for, unless it's HTML5 validation or something similar.

Comment: @elclanrs It fails for "0" and "1"; I do agree with the simple check, though.

Comment: @user2864740 - just removing the strict checks fixes that

Comment: Well, I'm assuming OP would cast a number if he wants to compare numbers but also `==`

Comment: If you use `==` with `0`, then I believe you will also match `null` and other falsy values.

Comment: As it's clearly coming from an input field, null won't be an issue, and it will always be of type string, so I don't really see the problem.

Comment: So what *is* the input - only "0" and "1"? Or is "1001" allowed? What about "" (no input)? And why should a regular expression be used?

Comment: The solution can be found here as I think.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1679477/how-to-match-1-0-with-regular-expression

Comment: Stop overthinking and just use `if (string==="0" || string==="1")`.

Comment: Wondering why this hasn't been CVed yet...

Comment: @adeneo assuming it's 'clearly coming from a field' does not support code reuse, and couples the code to some UI mapping/sanitize dependency for gatekeeping for nulls etc.

Answer (score 10):

Single character, 0 or 1:

```
/^[01]$/
```

Multiple 0s or 1s (any order, no other characters):

```
/^[01]+$/g
```

[Demo](http://refiddle.co/h2m) (Just add a `+` for the second example.  The `gm` at the end in the demo is just for the example because there are multiple lines for test cases)

Comment: idk?  I didn't do it but maybe its because you have to have a login account for the link?

Comment: That's a good possibility.  I didn't notice that (since I'm logged in).  I'll see what I have to do to get the public, shareable link.

Comment: Ok, I just had to set the share option.  Should be available now (but if not, let me know)

Comment: yeah...looks good now...i +1'd ya so you're not negative on a good answer :)

Comment: The succinct description is potentially misleading. While the first one validates that the input has 1 character, and it is 0 or 1, the second one only test whether there exists 0 and 1 in the input (the input may contain other things).

Comment: Good point and completely true, thanks @nhahtdh! I'll update my answer to be more clear and more correct.

Comment: I'll also update my demo to include some test cases with other characters.

Answer (score 0):

A simple `0|1` expression should work.

Answer (score 0):

```
([01])
```

http://rubular.com/r/TMu6vsx6Dn

If you only want the first occurrence, this will work as well.

```
(^[01])
```

http://rubular.com/r/i3brvRutCg

Comment: As I understand the question, he wants to match any one's or zeros? that's what this does?

Answer (score 0):

Try this regex: `/^(0|1)$/`

Example:

```
/^(0|1)$/.test(0); // true
/^(0|1)$/.test(1); // true
/^(0|1)$/.test(2); // false
/^(0|1)$/.test(1001) // false
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest simple string evaluation here since you have only two known acceptable values in the input string:

```
var input; // Your input string assume it is populated elsewhere
if (input === '0' || input === '1') {
   // Pass
}
```

Note the use of strict string comparison here to eliminate matches with truthy/falsey values.

If you are really hell-bent on a regex, try:

```
/^[01]$/
```

The key here is the beginning `^` and ending `$` anchors.